# Upload configuration files as artifact or assets for a python wheel task depending on target

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-asset-bundle

I could not find any answers in the [Databricks' documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/index.html) or even the current [databricks-cli repository](https://github.com/databricks/cli) and I faced a problem during my migration from [dbx](https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbx) setup. The migration [example](https://docs.databricks.com/en/archive/dev-tools/dbx/dbx-migrate.html#converting-dbx-deployment-settings-to-databricksyml) in the documentation is quite reduced and do not cover other aspects of the deployment as parameter files for the jobs.

My use case is the bundle deployment of a python wheel job with parameters passed as a file.

```yaml
# The main job for package_name
artifacts:
  package_wheel:
    build: poetry build
    path: ..
    type: whl
  config_file:
    build: echo Under build
    files:
      - source: test_conf.yaml
    path: ../conf
    type: yaml

resources:
  jobs:
    package_name_job:
      name: package_name_job

      schedule:
        quartz_cron_expression: '44 37 8 * * ?'
        timezone_id: Europe/Amsterdam

      email_notifications:
        on_failure:
          - my.name@mycompany.com

      tasks:
        - task_key: main_task
          job_cluster_key: job_cluster
          python_wheel_task:
            package_name: package_name
            entry_point: main
            parameters: ["--conf-file", config_file]
          libraries:
            # By default we just include the .whl file generated for the package_name package.
            # See https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/bundles/library-dependencies.html
            # for more information on how to add other libraries.
            - whl: ../dist/*.whl

      job_clusters:
        - job_cluster_key: job_cluster
          new_cluster:
            spark_version: 13.3.x-scala2.12
            node_type_id: n1-standard-4
            autoscale:
                min_workers: 1
                max_workers: 4
```

I just want to configure the job to deploy using different `config_files` depending on the `targets` described in my `databricks.yaml` file. However I am not able of making databrick-cli automatically recognize that files as `artifacts` and upload them to the `.bundle/[package_name]/[target]/files` path as the built wheel is copied/uploaded to the `.bundle/[package_name]/[target]/artifacts.

I tried to define the config-file as an artifact and use the reference but it does not work.

```yaml
# The main job for package_name
artifacts:
  ...
  config_file:
    build: echo Under build
    files:
      - source: test_conf.yaml
    path: ../conf
    type: yaml

resources:
  jobs:
    package_name_job:
      name: package_name_job

      ...

      tasks:
        - task_key: main_task
          job_cluster_key: job_cluster
          python_wheel_task:
            package_name: package_name
            entry_point: main
            parameters: ["--conf-file", ${artifacts.config_file}] # <-- Reference as in terraform?
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out ✅

The trick was made by using the `sync` configuration parameter inside the `targets` definition in the `databricks.yml` bundle definition file.

Just to clarify, my python package is handle by [poetry] so I have this project structure:

```
[project]
  |
  |- pyproject.toml
  |- databricks.yml
  |- [resources]
  |   |- package_name_job.yml
  |- [conf]
  |   |- [dev] # The same as `target`
  |       |- job_conf.yml
  |- [src]
  |   |- [python_package_name]
  |       |- __init__.py
  |       |- main.py
```

`databricks.yml`

```yaml
bundle:
  name: package_name

include:
  - resources/*.yml

targets:
  dev:
    mode: development
    default: true
    workspace:
      host: https://myhost.databricks.com
      profile: develop
    sync:
      include: # This makes folder "conf" to be included into the bundle/files path. By default to `${workspace.root}/files/conf`
      - conf/
```

Then, I use the reference in the job definition

`package_name_job.yml`

```yaml
# This allow me to build the poetry package in dist folder as the artifact.
artifacts:
  package_wheel:
    build: poetry build
    path: ..
    type: whl

resources:
  jobs:
    package_name_job:
      name: package_name_job

      tasks:
        - task_key: main_task
          job_cluster_key: job_cluster
          python_wheel_task:
            package_name: package_name
            entry_point: main
            parameters:
            # ${bundle.target} == dev (for this example) 
              - "--conf-file"
              - ${workspace.root_path}/files/conf/${bundle.target}/test_conf.yaml
          libraries:
            - whl: ../dist/*.whl

      job_clusters:
        - job_cluster_key: job_cluster
          new_cluster:
            spark_version: 13.3.x-scala2.12
            node_type_id: n1-standard-4
            autoscale:
                min_workers: 1
                max_workers: 4
```

By creating new folders with the same configuration file name for each `target` this allow me to deploy de job with a different configuration file depending on the `target` and using the same logic, thus not-modifying my source code, just configuration.

Comment: HI! Did you perhaps try the dynamic insert of job clusters with a conf file?